# Converting decimal to 2's complement

Tags: binary, binary-data, data-conversion

I am working on converting decimal numbers to 2's Complement binary numbers.
I understand the concept;

1. Convert the number to Hex (Base 16)
2. Convert the result into binary (padding to 8-digits)
3. Invert all bits and add 1

so I have been trying to convert 92(base 10)

```
92 -> Hex = 5c
5C == 5 12 -> Binary = 01011100
Inverting = 10100011
           +       1
           =10100100
```

But an online converter I used to check my answer says: 01011100 
What did I do wrong? I know that the most-significant bit should be 0, as the number is positive. But other than that, I am confused.

**update**

Is this because positive numbers do not need to be switched for sign magnitude?
Therefore, the number remains the same before and after doing 2's complement?

Meaning, the answer that I obtained is ***actually*** the negative interpretation; -92?

Comment: remember If you have a 1 in the MSB then you're saying it's a negative number in 2's compliment.

Comment: Right! I know that, but I think I may have accidentally inverted the number when I didn't need to.

Comment: The only guess that I have here is that the assignment has been to start with negative 92, i.e. `A4`, or `10100100` and then obtain its two's complement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only invert it and add 1 when you're trying to represent a negative number, positive numbers are represented with normal binary.  (You just get less range in the positive numbers).

Comment: Ok, so the number that I obtained is indeed the negative representation of 92?

Comment: Yes. you followed the correct procedure to represent -92 in 2's compliment.